# c# webbrowser two inputs at the same value

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Use c# webbrowser.

There are two inputs in html that have the same class name.

I want to enter data into these separately.

id and name not found. Only class defined.

```
  foreach (HtmlElement btn in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "rw-input rw-dropdown-list-input")
                {
                    btn.InnerText = "Lassa";
                    break;
                }
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "rw-input rw-dropdown-list-input")  
                {
                    btn.InnerText = "Ferrari";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could just retrieve all `div` with the appropriate class name, and then you assign your labels.

*Example:*

```
List<HtmlElement> buttons = new List<HtmlElement>();

// Iterate in the DIV elements to retrieve elements with the appropriate class name
foreach (HtmlElement divElement in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
    if (divElement.GetAttribute("className") == "rw-input rw-dropdown-list-input") {
        buttons.Add(divElement);
    }
}

// Assign the label values.
buttons[0].InnerText = "Lassa";
buttons[1].InnerText = "Ferrari";
```